# Is it possible read YAML property from annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need pass a db shchema to annotation, it is possible read from annotation without create a intermediate variable?

Something like that -

```
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "${DB_ESCHEMA} + SEQ.ID")
  private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use Spring EL in JPA annotations.

But why do you are you using the schema name? Isn't it the same as the rest of the tables?

Comment: The BD user configuration (privileges) forces me to specify the schema name in all the operations throwed to BD.

Comment: You can define the schema globally spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema.

Comment: The application consumes two differents BD with different schemes.